# Why does less css behave differently when served over port 80 than other ports?

Tags: css, jsp, caching, nginx, less

I have a site which has the capability to change branding.  When branding changes various colours change.  To enable this, the site utilizes less (as in lesscss.org) and one included jsp (called style.jsp) has various less variables which then change the look of the site.

All of this works fine when I run locally with the site served up on port 8080.

When I deployed this to our QA site we noticed it appeared to be caching the colors, such that changing brands didn't change the colours.  On our QA site I redirect port 80 to port 8080 using nginx, so I tried accessing the site directly on port 8080 and it started working again.

After much head scratching I couldn't work out why there was any caching going on in nginx, so I tried something else.  I redirected port 8181 to port 8080 expecting it to still cache, but it didn't.  I've tried various ports and port 80 is the only one which seems to exhibit this caching behavior.

Does anyone know why it behaves differently on port 80 to any other port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else interested...
The less.js will be in development mode if the request is on any other port than port 80. In development mode the generated css is put in the standard browser cache as you'd expect.  In non-development mode, the css is put in a secret mystical cache that will not be affected by ctrl-r, shift-F5 etc.